# this is not return user_id in php with MySQL

Tags: php, pdo

```
try{
    $query = "SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE username = '".$username."'";

    $result = $dbhandle->query($query,PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    //$stmt->bindParam(":username",$username);

//  $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);


                while($row = $result->fetch()){

                    $id = $row['user_id'];


                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $id;

                    }

                }catch(PDOException $e){ echo $e->getMessage();}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code as sample code

```
  $DBH = new PDO( "connection string goes here" );
    $STH - $DBH -> prepare( "SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE username = '".$username."'" );
    $STH -> execute();
    $result = $STH -> fetch();
    echo $result ["user_id"];
    $DBH = null;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Updated for PDO. Can you pl chk